# notification shows but not loading next Activity

Tags: android, notifications

```
private void generateNotification() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String notificationTicket=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toLocaleString();
    long when=System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification myNotification=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notificationTicket, when);

    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyNewActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), null, "Hi some package Added", pendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);
}
```

I have used a button to fire notiification and it shows on my ActionBar but it doesn't load the new Activity I want. I have already define my NotificationManager earlier.
There is also a button for cancel notification but It doesn't worth as notification fire only for "some seconds". Thanks in Advance.

```
startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        stopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Still I am finding solution to run my notification successfully!!!!
I display the message but the activity which I am tring to trigger after notified to user,is not working....
I just require a single demo of notification which give the result and I will complete the rest. Thanks again. I am looking for your kindly reply..

Comment: Please set more tags..

Answer (score 0):

**Try This..!**

```
 long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

 int i=(int) timestamp;


NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                             .setAutoCancel(true);;


 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

 stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyNewActivity.class);

 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

 PendingIntent pendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

  mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Intent resultIntent=new Intent(context,MyNewActivity.class);

Comment: mNotificationManager.cancel(i);-Write this before u call finish() and if u still get error then let me know..i will help u...!

Comment: hi pratik i have used your code bt still it's not working. It shows ClassNotFoundException for TaskStackBuilder class.

Comment: @lamExpo-late reply...check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html It is for Android 3.0 and newer. Download android-support-v4.jar and add it to ur Project's lib folder